# Check if integer ends with double zeros

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I check that an integer ends with two zeros (00)?

Thankful for all input!

Comment: You can check `num mod 100`?

Comment: You want integers with *exactly* two trailing zeros? Or *at least* two trailing zeros?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(1000%100).zero?
# => true

(1001%100).zero?
# => false
```

Comment: `0` passes this test, too

Comment: `!i.zero? && (i % 100).zero?` would cover the `0` case

Comment: Or `i / 100 > 0 and (i % 100).zero?`.

Comment: And 1000 should return *false*, the way I interpret the question.

Comment: @sawa good catch! `divmod` would be nice but requires temporary variables.

Comment: @sawa just checked it and it does *not* pass because `10 % 100` is not zero. BTW, your code doesn't work for negative integers. Many edge cases in this apparently simple question ...

Comment: @Stefan Sorry, that it was my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert it to `String`

```
100.to_s.end_with?("00")
```

Comment: The string conversion might be inefficient, but compared to the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25035596/477037) and its comments, this code is straightforward and clearly communicates what it does +1

Comment: Love Ruby for that, you can do everything you want :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want it to end with *exactly* two zeros, you can do this:

```
!!n.to_s.match(/[^0]00$/)
```

Comment: `Math.log10(200) #=> 2.3010299956639813`

Comment: @Stefan I gave up on `Math` and switched to regexp. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
x is the integer

x.to_s.end_with?('00')
```